# Passing variable from button to controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I am having a little routing problem in Laravel 5.2. I have a result page which shows detailed information about personnel. I would like a button, which when enabled, generates a PDF page. Passing the variables has been a problem but I am very close now! I will public my code to elaborate.

result page

```
<form action="generatePDFpage" method="get">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Generate PDF!</button>
</form>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard/result/generatePDFpage', 'resultController@GeneratePDFc');
```

GeneratePDFc controller

```
    public function GeneratePDFc(){

        $id_array_implode = "HALLO";    
        $pdf= PDF::loadView('GeneratePDF', ["test"=>$id_array_implode])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');    
        return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
    }
```

So, on the result page I am using a array ($id_array) to search the database for the matching records. I need to pass this variable onto the GeneratePDFc controller, so that I can pass that again to the loadView function!

Could someone please help me out? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using `get` method, you can do just this:

```
<a href="{{ route('route.name', $parameter) }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Generate PDF!</button>
</a>
```

For other methods you can use something like this (this one is for `DELETE` method):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('route.name', $parameter) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Generate PDF!</button>
<input type="hidden" value="someVariable" />
</form>
```

To get variable, use something like this:

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    $someVariable = $request->someVariable;
```

Comment: Oke, I have this. But how do I call the variable in the Controller?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, for GET, you need to create a route with a parameter and then pass it and catch with `function($parameter)`. When you're using forms you can use `hidden input` for that (look at updated code).

Comment: Thank you for explaining your code. I am still using the get method, but the 'someVariable' in my controller is undefined. Do you know a solution?

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, try to change you route to: `Route::get('/dashboard/result/generatePDFpage/{parameter}', ['as' => 'pdf', 'uses' => 'resultController@GeneratePDFc']);` and function to `function GeneratePDFc($parameter)`. Then just pass the parameter like I did in my answer with `route('pdf', $parameter)`

Comment: I'm not sure that passing an array as a GET parameter is a good way to go, the URL will look creepy and maybe will have invalid characters. @AnnaJeanine you should add a parameter to the route in your routes file in order to receive the variable in your controller function.

Comment: @GerardReches, well sometimes it's not creepy, like `/city/Amsterdam` or `/id/2`. But for ugly data yes, it's better to use `POST`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yeah, a `POST` will be better for this specific case where she wants an array.

Comment: @GerardReches, agreed. The original question is using `GET`. That's why I've posted code for both `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Thank you very much! It is working!  Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel but I think when in your `action=""` of the form you can put your route with its parameters no ?

I've found it here : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form

And access the variable in your controller using the `$request` var